# Запустить скрипт в потоке с другим интерпретатором

Tags: python, python-3.x, многопоточность, virtualenv

У меня есть скрипт, который выполняется одним интерпретатором (виртуальное окружение). Мне из него нужно создать поток, который запустит другой скрипт с другим интерпретатором (тоже виртуальное окружение). Как это сделать?

Пробовал передавать все в `os.system()` - возникает ошибка

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module name'
```

Попробовал поставить зависимости из вызываемого интерпретатора окружения в это окружение - та же самая ошибка

Пробовал добавить перед вызовом скрипта в `os.system()` `source /path/to/venv/bin/activate;` - тоже не помогло.

Как можно это сделать?

Вызов происходит так:

```
th = threading.Thread(target=os.system, args=(params,))
th.start()
```

upd. Попробовал в вызываемом скрипте сделать

```
sys.path.append('/путь/к/вызывающей/программе')
```

Тоже не помогло

upd. Добавил пример:

```
# Вызывающий скрипт
import threading
import os

th = threading.Thread(target=os.system, args=('/path/to/flask/app.py',))
th.start()
```

---

```
# Вызываемый скрипт
#!/usr/bin/python3

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Если выполнить вызывающий скрипт, то получим

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/path/to/flask/app.py", line 3, in <module>
from flask import Flask
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

потому что у интерпретатор вызывающего скрипта нет flask (модуль взят только для примера)

Answer (score 0):

как пример - запуск этого-же файла, но рекурсивно с другим интерпретатором, импортируя при этом lib_new.settings, путем смены текущей домашней директории в cwd_to_lib_folder, которая может отличатся в новом процессе, от той, в которой запускали главный запускающий файл

```
import subprocess, os, sys

def cwd_to_lib_folder(lib_folder='lib_new', dsk=True)  -> str:
    """ нужно что-то такое, для импорта, при выполнении в отдельном python процессе.
    т.е. найти каталог lib_folder, и сменить текущую директорию, для импорта польз. модулей, при неверной домашней директории
    """
    path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    while lib_folder not in next(os.walk(path))[1]:
        path = os.path.join(path, '..')
        if dsk:
            os.chdir(path[:2])
            path = False
        os.chdir(path)
    sys.path.append(path)
    return path

###
try:  # импорт lib_new.settings при обычном запуске
    Path = os.getcwd()
    import lib_new.settings
except:    # импорт lib_new.settings при запуске с другим интерпретатором
    Path = cwd_to_lib_folder()
    import lib_new.settings
###

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 2:
        a = int(sys.argv[1])
    else:
        a = 1
    if a < 10:
        sp = subprocess.Popen(['python', __file__, str(a+1)])  # запустить этот-же скрипт, но с другим интерпретатором 
        sp.communicate()
        print(a)
```

out:

```
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Comment: Не особо понял, что здесь происходит и что нужно импортировать. Я добавил пример для большей ясности. Можно ваше решение приспособить к примеру? :)

Answer (score 0):

Нашел решение, которое, я уверен, не самое элегантное, но рабочее. В вызывающем скрипте управление нужно передать интерпретатору `os.system` (то есть `bash` в моем случае). Его содержимое:

```
#!/bin/bash

source $1
python3 $2
```

где `$1` - путь до вашего venv/bin/activate, и `$2` - путь до вызываемого скрипта. Таким образом в вызывающем скрипте мы пишем

```
import threading
import os

th = threading.Thread(target=os.system, args=('solve.sh /home/path/to/venv/bin/activate /home/path/to/app.py',))
th.start()
```

таким образом будет получен экземпляр системного интерпретатора, который затем зайдет в виртуальное окружение и выполнит скрипт в нем.